# BillingAddress in query generate error

Tags: apex, dynamic-soql, geolocation

I have a query like below in an Apex Class in Sandbox.

```
query = 'SELECT Id, Name, BillingAddress, BillingLatitude, BillingLongitude  FROM   Account WHERE Name = \''+ name +'\' AND ';
query += 'DISTANCE(BillingAddress, GEOLOCATION('+lat+', '+lng+'), \'km\') < '+distance+' ORDER BY DISTANCE(BillingAddress, GEOLOCATION('+lat+', '+lng+'), \'km\') ASC';
```

It works perfect in sandbox. But when I try to deploy this class to live, it generate this error:

> System.QueryException: No such column 'BillingAddress' on entity 'Account'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

What are the possible reasons?

Comment: I presume the class is set to an [API version beyond 30](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/compound_fields_address.htm) in both cases?

Comment: @KeithC Yes, you are right. API version is 34 for both

Comment: I am seeing the same error. I doubt this is some compilation error but not able to trace the root cause. Please share how you fixed it and what was the issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @SaumyaRanjanSatapathy check the API version of your class. `BillingAddress` is supported in API version 30 and beyond.
In my case, the API versions were correct and still was not able to deploy code, the problem solved somewhat mysteriously. I never knew what was the problem but it just started working.

Answer (score 2):

you should use the [actual fields](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/compound_fields_address.htm) in your query... BillingCity, BillingStreet, BillingCountry... etc... same goes for mailing Address - they are special compound fields that holds few fields inside...

Comment: I can remove the `BillingAddress` from `SELECT` clause, but I really need it in the `WHERE` clauses. Without this I cannot find Accounts within a radius.

Comment: There is no problem with that.. you can use whatever filter you will choose - you just need to be more specific then 'Address' - you should filter by street, city, postalCode etc..

Comment: If you see I have used `DISTANCE` formula in the `WHERE` clause. It does not accept individual values.

Comment: check out this link on how to query Distance : https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000AdhCIAS

Comment: I am exactly doing same, except that, they are using a custom location field and I am using Standerd Compound fields as Locations. See last topic on [this link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/compound_fields_address.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the issue is due to Field Level Security (FLS). First log in to your production environment, find the BillingAddress field and ensure that the profile you are using to deploy the class to production has at least Read access tot he BillingAddress field.

Comment: The deploying profile is Admin and has access to the field. I confirmed it. It has access to the BillingAddress individual field like BillingState etc. The BillingAddress field is also accessed from developer consoles. But simply not working in this class.